# How to handle non-persistent data to show in ListView?

Tags: android, persistence

I am working on an app that serves as a thin client. The app will be in constant TCP connection with a server and the amount of data flowing between them will be very small, only textual.

How should I handle the data, considering this is a typical scenario:

- App is started, establish TCP connection to server
- The server sends some data, save this data and display them in a ListView
- User interacts with the app, server will asynchronously send data, it should be appended to the ListView

I was thinking there might be the main activity havin a member List where it would store the objects to show in the ListView. Upon (asynchronously) receiving some new data, the main thread would be notified and it would reflect the changes on the ListView.

Is there a better, *cleaner* way? Implementing a contentprovider and using a Loader seems a bit too much, considering I really don't need the data to persist.

Comment: Well this seems good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own application extending **android.app.Application** and your List will be an attribute of your application.

Then using the Context into your AsyncTask you can add the content get asynchronously into your List.

Finally a nice way to update the ListView could be to register your ListActivity as a Listener of all changes of the List content. For example implementing :

```
public interface IListChangeListener {
    public void onContentChange();
}
```

For each modifications of the List content your application will loop on all the listeners to invoke onContentChange();

On your list activity you will have to implement :

```
public void onContentChange(){
    // Reload the list adapter content and all the notifyDataSetChanged here 
}
```

Don't forget to deregister the ListActivity as listener when it will be destroyed...